# Understanding multiple middlewares on a group of endpoints on NodeJs and Express

Tags: node.js, express

During refactoring my application (HTTP Server) I decided to save all the requests somewhere using a middleware.
I used to separate the entities so each one of them has its own API router endpoints and views.

For example, when I call an endpoint like `/api/notifications/latest` one time the middleware runs 3 times for some reason.
Another example is when I simply visit the home page at `/` the middleware runs twice.

Here is a part of my code in `./server.js` where I setup the routes:

```
app.use('/', require('./api/auth'));
app.use('/', require('./api/pages'));
app.use('/api', require('./api/user'));
app.use('/api', require('./api/notifications'));
app.use('/api', require('./api/product'));
app.use('/api', require('./api/category'));
```

Each one of these routes uses `router.use([logs.log_endpoints, auth.check_token])` before defining the enfpoints.

For example, the routes under `./api/notifications` are defined like this:

```
// Imports
const router = express.Router();
// Register middlewawres
router.use([logs.log_endpoints, auth.check_token]);
// Endpoints
router.get('/notifications', (req, res) => { return [...]; });
// Exports
module.exports = router;
```

Please let me know if should I upload more information about the problem.

Regards,

Comment: `router.use('/notifications', [logs.log_endpoints...`

Comment: what if I have 500 endpoints? not only ```router.get('/notifications',```

Comment: Just register middleware once for all of them. For example, register  `auth.check_token` for `app`, then register all auth required routers.

Answer (score 1):

You are reusing the same path structure multiple times. If you need to simply route the APIs to different routes (routers) trying including that in the path so that you have different paths for different routes instead of your code trying to run multiple times in order to figure out where that specific route is. E.g. changing them this ways should help:

```
app.use('/auth', require('./api/auth'));
app.use('/pages', require('./api/pages'));
app.use('/api/user', require('./api/user'));
app.use('/api/notifications', require('./api/notifications'));
app.use('/api/product', require('./api/product'));
app.use('/api/category', require('./api/category'));
```